# Calling Node/Axios from frontend

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios, ejs

I have a nodeJS/Axios/Express application I am working on.  I have written the frontend using express, and have a form that I want to be able to use to send data to a function that uses axios.  When I try to run it I am getting an error that require is not defined.  How would I be able to submit the form and pass the data to my function to be executed?

I am using EJS so some of the HTML may look like its missing parts because its part of a different file.

Here is one of the functions.  It runs correctly if I execute it with code order_handler.js

```
const axios = require('axios');
const helper = require('../helper_functions');
const qs = require('qs');
const session = require('./get_login');

async function getProdData(slug) {
var sessionid = await session.initSession('<username>', '<password>');

var config = {
    headers: {
        'User-Agent':   'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:58.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/58.0',
        cookie: `sessionid=${sessionid.sessionCookie}; _gat=1`,
    },
}

return axios.get('<3rd party API>' + slug + '/?format=json',config)
.then(res => {
    var data = res.data;
    console.log(data);
})
.catch(err => {
    console.error(err); 
})
}
```

Here is the HTML form on the frontend:

```
<script src="./order_handler.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="POST">
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="sku">Item Lookup by SKU</label>
  <input
    type="text"
    id="text"
    name="Item SKU"
    class="form-control"
    placeholder="Enter SKU"
  />
</div>
<button type="submit" onsubmit="getProductData()" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Find</button>
</form>
```

From what I have found in my research it seems the issue is because the browser does not understand the require's at the top of my script file.  I just cant figure out what the easiest way to get these functions to be executed with data from a form on the frontend.

Comment: require can't be used on the frontend unless you're using some sort of asset bundler like Webpack. The web browser does not natively support require.

Comment: So without using webpack would the solution be to write my back-end functions in a way that exposes an API that I could POST to from the front-end?

Comment: It depends on if you want to do AJAX calls, or if you are find with submitting data and handling redirects. You could set up a route that the form sends the form data to and then your backend route processes the data and then redirects the user to a different page.

Comment: I would prefer to use AJAX calls so the page does not have to reload, and can return data from the function.

Comment: Your safest bet would be to use JavaScript that your browser understands then for making your ajax requests. This would mean no requires, and your api requests would use fetch instead of axios.

Comment: Thank you!  I appreciate the help!  I am kind of new to Stack Overflow not sure if I can make your comment the answer to my question to give you credit? :)

Comment: Not possible unfortunately, but don't worry about it. Have a great day and good luck!